# Practical REPL use with Java 9

Tags: read-eval-print-loop, java, java-9

I'm learning [REPL](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/222) for Java 9 and how to utilize it effectively. Considering Java is heavy on the configuration and external dependencies this has made experiments for anything outside the trivial more work to configure than just waiting for a build/run.  For instance, to evaluate something more than a trivial line of Java, based on just its runtime, one has to reference an external library as well as its own dependencies. This over-complicates things and perhaps make the point of such a feature moot for real-world scenarios.

Until IDE's integrate REPL and automatically manage/inject dependent libraries, how does one use the feature without the feature becoming more of a burden then the hurdle it was meant to overcome? Please note I'm not looking for conjecture, but methods in which one has worked to accomplish this.

I'm using the Kulla repo [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/kulla/dev) to experiment.

Comment: I could not even find `jshell` within JDK 9...

Answer (score 2):

As of October 2015 REPL (project Kulla) is still is not integrated, and Modular JDK, runtime images goes as second alternative download. Once they are all integrated in Dec 2015, there should start work and testing of them together.

As of October 2015 all tutorials suggest starting from building sources:

1. [JDK 9 REPL: Getting Started (Tech Tip #87)](http://blog.arungupta.me/jdk9-repl-getting-started/)
2. [REPL_Tutorial.pdf](https://java.net/downloads/adoptopenjdk/REPL_Tutorial.pdf)
3. [JShell and REPL in Java 9](https://blogs.oracle.com/java/entry/jshell_and_relp_in_java)
4. [Java9-New-HTTP-2-and-REPL](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Java9-New-HTTP-2-and-REPL)

Comment: I've been rolling my own to test as you mentioned. Your answer doesn't really address my question, though the PDF link you included does help to clarify some dependency questions.

Comment: I've had things working to test. Though, im telling you your post doesn't answer the question.